# Joomla 301 redirect index.php urls after sef-urls

Tags: .htaccess

I have a joomla website on which i turned on the sef-urls. Now the new urls and the urls with index.php are working:
https://www.myurl.ch/index.php/team
https://www.myurl.ch/team

I want to redirect all the index.php urls to non index.php versions so /index.php/team should redirect to /team.

How can i set this in my .htaccess File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

This will redirect **/index.php/foobar** to **/foobar** .